How do we add a dropdown on click of a custom button in Full Calendar
I am working on a project using FullCalendar, and I need to add a dropdown menu that appears when a custom button in the header is clicked. I've successfully added the custom button, but I'm struggling with the dropdown functionality.
Here's what I have so far for adding the custom button:
headerToolbar: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'customButton'
},
customButtons: {
    customButton: {
        text: 'Options',
        click: function() {
            // This is where I need to show the dropdown
            console.log('Custom button clicked!');
        }
    }
}

I'm not sure how to proceed from here to display a dropdown menu. Ideally, the dropdown would have options like "Option 1", "Option 2", and "Option 3". I would also like to handle the selection of these options to perform different actions based on the user's choice.
Has anyone implemented a similar feature or can provide guidance on how to achieve this? Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated!



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>FullCalendar with Dropdown Menu</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.1/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    .dropdown-menu {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: white;
      box-shadow: 0 8px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-menu button {
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-align: left;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .dropdown-menu button:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="calendar"></div>

  <div id="dropdownMenu" class="dropdown-menu">
    <button onclick="optionSelected('Option 1')">Option 1</button>
    <button onclick="optionSelected('Option 2')">Option 2</button>
    <button onclick="optionSelected('Option 3')">Option 3</button>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.1/main.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
      var dropdownMenu = document.getElementById('dropdownMenu');

      var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        headerToolbar: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'customButton'
        },
        customButtons: {
          customButton: {
            text: 'Options',
            click: function(event) {
              var rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
              dropdownMenu.style.display = 'block';
              dropdownMenu.style.left = rect.left + 'px';
              dropdownMenu.style.top = (rect.bottom + window.scrollY) + 'px';
            }
          }
        }
      });

      calendar.render();

      // Hide dropdown when clicking outside
      document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        if (!event.target.matches('.fc-customButton-button')) {
          dropdownMenu.style.display = 'none';
        }
      });
    });

    function optionSelected(option) {
      alert(option + ' selected!');
      // Perform actions based on the selected option
      document.getElementById('dropdownMenu').style.display = 'none';
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>




Although this approach seems promising, I'm still struggling to execute it correctly. Could you please share the StackBlitz project with me? It would greatly help to visualize the implementation.
